# Which transformation is more powerful, the original white-grey hair ultra instinct, or ultra instinct stacked on top of a super saiyan transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

So now Goku is able to stack Ultra Instinct on top of other transformations. In the chapter of the manga before the last he stacked Ultra Instinct on top of super saiyan god. In the last chapter he did it again with another transformation.

Which transformation is supposed to be more powerful, the original white-grey hair ultra instinct, or ultra instinct stacked on top of a super saiyan transformation?

Answer (score 0):

> Which transformation is supposed to be more powerful…?

The stacked transformation.

If you put SSJ on UI it's going to be stronger, since we know that SSJ is a 50x multiplier. So, we know that Great Ape is 10 times stronger than base form saiyans, and that Super Saiyan is a 50 times multiplier of base power level. Then, SSJ 2 is a 100 times multiplier (or 2 times stronger than SSJ), and SSJ 3 is 400 times stronger than base (or 8 times SSJ).

However, if UI causes Goku to lose stamina **heavily**, that means if he stacks a transformation on top, that will be overkill and he would lose his stamina in the snap of a finger.